# Is there any way to collect data from an Interactive Grid, and send it via the page's email process?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a form that has five fields and an interactive grid. After I click "Send", I created a process to send an email to the requester, and in this process, I can send the information that is filled in each field of the form, using the APEX variables &P10_FIELDNAME.

My question is: how do I send the information that is passed in the interactive grid?

Remembering that: this interactive grid is only for INSERT. That is, the grid will always be empty when filling out the form.

[My form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nErOb.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a page process to pick up the data from an interactive grid in pl/sql as shown in this screenshot: it is a basic interactive grid on the EMP sample table:

[image: screenshot]

This process is being executed *for every updated/inserted row of the grid*, the "editable" region needs to be set to the IG region, the individual columns can be reference with the bind variable syntax (column ENAME can be referenced as `:ENAME`).

There are many blogs on this, for example [here](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/customizing-dml-in-an-apex-interactive-grid/) and [here](https://www.capancioni.com/using-oracle-tapi-in-an-apex-form/) (I just picked those 2 at random)

Now to answer your question specifically, you'll have to go through a number of steps to send this data, together with other page data in an email, just because the pl/sql code in this process is executed in every row. What you could do is

- In the IG custom process, add the data to a collection (using the `APEX_COLLECTION` api.
- In a page process that executes *after* this IG custom process, loop through the collection with the IG data to populate the email and include the other page items as well